# Bootstrap progress bar not progressing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The bootstrap progress bar is not working on my MVC index view.
I have tried it with Chrome and Internet Explorer.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Getting started</h2>
     <div class="progress-bar progress-striped "></div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link?

Comment: what version of bootstarp you are using???? did you include the `bootstrap.js` file???

Comment: @user3381280 Please provide demo link

Answer (score 20):

Late to this party, but in the version of Bootstrap I'm using (v3.1.1) the class was 'progress-striped' (not 'progress-bar-striped' like the Docs say) and both it and the 'active' class had to be applied to the outer div:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Grim... , It helped me. I am using Bootstrap 3 in an old project and striped wasn't working. Applied it to the outer div and it started working.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the CSS, the selector "progress-bar" has been changed to "bar":

```
./bootstrap.css:

.progress {
...
}

.progress .bar {
...
}
```

So, change your code to

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then it will work.

Not sure what reasoning there is for this insanity, seems like the bootstrap docs just havent been updated.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
</div>
```

With this the progress animation will work.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 5 and I get no animation as this fiddle site with show: https://www.codeply.com/p/uRBwIAB8Is

Comment: @chad I opened your codeply link and I do see animation (Windows 11, MS Edge). Perhaps it was a browser issue on your end?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bootstrap v4 and need to animate, you will need to use `progress-bar-animated` instead of `active`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
   <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Above is the code from bootstrap v3.1.1 looks like you're progress bar div is missing some elements?